# customized logarithmic d3 chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to create a d3 chart with logarithmic scale(1,10,100..). I used their functions and call but not much help.

```
var x = d3.scale.log()
    .domain([1,10])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.log()
    .domain([1,10])
    .range([height, 0]);

var color = d3.scale.category10();

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)   
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)   
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d[xAxxis]); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d[yAxxis]); });
var svg = d3.select("#"+this.divid).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

x.domain(d3.extent(totalArray, function(d) { return d[xAxxis]; })).nice(); 
y.domain(d3.extent(totalArray, function(d) { return d[yAxxis]; })).nice();
```

Is there any way i can create the axis with 1e+0,10e+0,100e+0 rather than 1e+0,2e+0,3e+0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control which labels the axis renders using either the `tick()` or `tickValues()` method, depending on how you want to go about it. See the [d3's API documentation for more details](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-ticks). Also, note that a log scale's `tick()` method [takes no arguments](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-log_ticks), so you'll likely have to use `tickValues()` though the other method might come in handy for formatting.